# how to remove personal certificate from personal store of internet explorer using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to remove all the certs in the personal store signed by the httpproxyserver cert. using Unistall() of Installer.cs.

I have tried this code but not get successed. even not get any certificate name.

```
X509Store personalStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

personalStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in personalStore.Certificates)
{
    personalStore.Remove(cert);
}
```

can you give me any idea for remove certies..?